# Changing pipeline location file path

Tags: java, jar, gstreamer, rtp

Is it possible to change a pipeline location file path after it finished running first location .wav file?
I've tried the following but it didn't worked:

```
    Element source = ElementFactory.make("filesrc","src");
    pipeline.link(source);
    source.set("location", newPath);
```

The main goal is to use the same pipeline during the code process - I've seen some strange behavior of gstreamer when creating too many pipelines or buses...

Comment: You could always write your own "pipelines" to do that, shouldnt take a lot of effort considering your current goal

Answer (score -1):

There is a GStreamer elements that already handles that use case  easily by reading sequentially named files, you can try to use `multifilesrc`.